# How to dynamically enable or disable ion-range-slider using Ionic 3 and Angular 5?

Tags: ionic3, angular5, ion-range-slider

I have implemented a slider using ion-range-slider. It is having a disable option to make the slider enable or disable. But I need to make it enable/disable dynamically.

I tried this way. I am not able to achieve this. Please help me what I need to do?
Her's the code.

```
<ion-range-slider #advancedSliderElement
                  type="single"
                  [min]="0"
                  max="100"
                  from={{r.rule}}    
                  from_shadow="true"
                  to="40"
                  to_shadow="true"
                  grid="true"
                  grid_num="10"
                  prefix=""
                  postfix=""
                  decorate_both="false"
                  disable = "rangeDisable"
                  (onChange)="update(advancedSlider, $event)"
                  (onFinish)="finish(advancedSlider, $event, i)">
            </ion-range-slider>
```

My manage.ts code is:

```
export class ManagePage {
public rangeDisable: boolean = true;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}
enableSave() {
        this.rangeDisable = false;
    }
}
```

I need to make slider enable on click of a button

```
<button class="button-border" ion-button round (click)="enableSave()" ><i class="material-icons">create</i> </button>
```

Please guide me how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `[]` to bind your boolean variable to the property of the component.

```
<ion-range-slider #advancedSliderElement
                  type="single"
                  min="0"//no need to bind if you are sending a value
                  max="100"
                  [from]="r.rule"  
                  from_shadow="true"
                  to="40"
                  to_shadow="true"
                  grid="true"
                  grid_num="10"
                  prefix=""
                  postfix=""
                  decorate_both="false"
                  [disable] = "rangeDisable"//here
                  (onChange)="update(advancedSlider, $event)"
                  (onFinish)="finish(advancedSlider, $event, i)">
            </ion-range-slider>
```

Comment: thank you so much, I didn't know we can bind other properties with just giving brackets.

Comment: @Darshantheerth you might want to check out the Angular tutorial, this will prevent a lot of headache in the future ;) https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax its angulars data binding.. your library is also built on angular and uses [`input()`](https://github.com/PhilippStein/ng2-ion-range-slider/blob/master/src/ion-range-slider.component.ts#L16) to bind data. I suggest you go through the docs